# Problem sending email with From header equal to my alias of google apps account, not my self google apps account

Tags: django, email, smtp, google-apps

I have an email account at Google Apps, (**myaccount@mydomain.com**), and for this account I created an alias(**myalias@mydomain.com**).

My intention is to send email through my account(**myaccount@mydomain.com**) but using the alias(**myalias@mydomain.com**) at 'From' header.

The following Django code shows what I'm trying to do:

```
params = {
  'host' : "smtp.gmail.com",
  'port' : 587,
  'username' : "myaccount@mydomain.com",
  'password' : "12345",  #my pass for myaccount
  'use_tls' : True,
}
connection=get_connection('django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend',**params)

def send_email(subject, body, from_email, to):
  headers={
    'From': from_email,
  }
  email = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject=subject, 
                                 body=body, 
                                 from_email=from, 
                                 to=[to],
                                 connection=connection,
                                 headers=headers)
  return email.send()

send_email("testing", "Hi, my friend", "myalias@mydomain.com", "foo@bardomain.com")
```

The problem is that when "foo" receives my message he doesn't see **myalias@mydomain**, as remitent, he sees **myaccount@mydomain.com** instead.

I checked the raw message and I don't see any part of the original message including the email **myalias@mydomain.com** in the headers. Any idea what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

As you have tagged google-apps, I assume you are using Google as your SMTP server.  By default google sends from the primary account.

To change this, login to the gmail interface, go to the Settings, and choose Accounts.

You should have a group called send mail as - add the alias you want to use to that list & the Django mails should come through as expected.